# Checkbox not getting checked in ionic2 ios10

Tags: ionic2

I am using the following code with ionic2

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Sausage</ion-label>
   <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="sausage"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But checkbox not getting checked for only IOS platform. Please help me.

Comment: Why there is `disabled="true"`?

Comment: Sorry, there is no disable attribute.